# Reuse Tensorflow session without making a checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to make a script that generates a prediction using a time series (UNIX Epoch time) and a value. I am creating different methods for each part of the script for aesthetic purposes. Here is an example:

```
def train_model(X_data, y_data):
   # Creating placeholders X and y

   # Creating optimizer and init variables

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       init.run()
       for epoch in range(200):
           for (xh, yh) in zip(X_data, y_data):
               sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: xh, y: yh})

       # Is it possible to return the trained model in a variable?

def make_pred(model, date):
    # Use the previous model to generate a prediction?
    with tf.Session() as sess:
       return sess.run(model, feed_dict={X: date})
```

How can I use the model created in the function `generate_model` without saving it in a checkpoint file?

Bonus questions:

- The model can't generate a prediction when the learning rate is 0.001 and I have to use a value close to 1e-20 to even see something other than NaN in my log. Is this happening because I didn't scale the time series array? What's the best way to scale them?
- As I don't have a lot of training data, should I use the whole set to train? How would a cross validation set work when I have less than 100 values? I am more interested in the predictions rather than visualising the results.

I am quite new to this so, if you see any terms out of their place, please don't hesitate to correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question

How can I use the model created in the function generate_model without saving it in a checkpoint file?

## Answer

Change your functions into a class and keep the session alive in the class like so

```
class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        init.run()

    def train_model(self, X_data, y_data):
        # Creating placeholders X and y
        for epoch in range(200):
           for (xh, yh) in zip(X_data, y_data):
               sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: xh, y: yh})

    def make_pred(self, date):
        # Use the previous model to generate a prediction yp
        return sess.run(yp, feed_dict={X: date})
```

create an instance of your class using `model = MyModel()` then train it like so `model.train_model(X_data,y_data)` and use it like so `model.make_pred(date)`.

## Bonus Question 1

The model can't generate a prediction when the learning rate is 0.001 and I have to use a value close to 1e-20 to even see something other than NaN in my log. Is this happening because I didn't scale the time series array? What's the best way to scale them?

## Bonus Answer 1

Choosing an appropriate learning rate is an important aspect of tuning your hyper parameters and it is not uncommon to get NaN (or other inappropriate values) with too high of a learning rate.

If you can scale your time series to be normalized, that would certainly help.  Try scaling your series to be between 0.0 and 1.0 or -1.0 and 1.0, whatever makes the most sense.

The best way to scale them depends on the data.  If your time series is outside temperature (for example) and is between -20C and +20C, then perhaps just T/20 (dividing it by 20) to normalize it would be great.  If you time series is cosmic temperatures of stellar gas and ranges between -270C and 50,000C , then perhaps log(T) would be better to just get the magnitude of the temperature

## Bonus Question 2

As I don't have a lot of training data, should I use the whole set to train? How would a cross validation set work when I have less than 100 values?

## Bonus Answer 2

Let's say you have 100 train data points.  You could make one predictor that used the first 20 data points for testing and the remainder for training.  You could then make another predictor that used the second 20 data points for testing and the other 80 for training, and so on so that you have 5 separately trained and tested predictors.  This would be a *5 fold* cross testing.  You know the reported test results of each predictor and you have 5 predictors (or N if you used N folds).

When you are using your predictors you would run your new data through each and have 5 estimates.  That now becomes your range of possible answers from your mini-collection of experts.  You could report on the average, RMS, high, and low of your answers.  All great information.